# React Electron Firebase Auth Popup closes after 1 second

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, electron, google-signin

I'm trying to Auth with the google popup from firebase in my react electron project. Now my problem: the popup shows up, but after 1 second, its closing by self again. I added `nativeWindowOpen: true` but it doesn't help. What can I do?

index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("node:path");

let mainWindow;
app.on("ready", () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      },
    },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(`${app.getAppPath()}\\build\\index.html`);
});

// ipcMain.on("LOOOOOOOOOOl", (event, value) => {
//   console.log(value);
// });
```

FirebaseConfig.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDCC5_C_XCp5YckJ2z0CkHZ1NyjvF2Wm_E",
  authDomain: "chatapp-edb8c.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "chatapp-edb8c",
  storageBucket: "chatapp-edb8c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "574617176079",
  appId: "1:574617176079:web:2eb2ba02d411abf28ebb7a",
  measurementId: "G-H2FD3WG691",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = getAuth(app);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { auth, provider };
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { auth, provider } from "./FirebaseConfig";
import { useState } from "react";
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

//electron
// const ipcRenderer = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer;
// //console.log(var); = ipcRenderer.send("name", var);

function App() {
  //auth firebase
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        setUser(user);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //error
      });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  //others
  // ipcRenderer.send("test", "Hello World!");
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>
            <h2>Welcome {user.displayName}</h2>
          </>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}>sign in with google</button>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried adding `nativeWindowOpen: true` in index.js. In another post, it worked for the others. But not for me.